# Visibility of BrowserModule and BrowserAnimationsModule?

Tags: angular

I have imported:

```
  imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule]
```

in `app.module`.

Should I import these modules in others custom modules and modules that lazy loaded?

I have the same situation with my custom module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, MaterialModule, RouterModule],
    declarations: [HeaderComponent, NavSearchComponent],
    exports: [HeaderComponent],
})
export class HeaderModule {}
```

Why when I import `HeaderModule` to another custom module, the custom moduels can not find component `HeaderComponent`?

Comment: No need to import any other modules.

Comment: See my updated question please

Comment: BrowserModule and BrowserAnimationsModule should only be imported once, you will eventually get errors if you import them twice. Regarding HeaderModule yes, you'd import it into another module where you want to use it. How are you importing it and what is exactly the error that says HeaderComponent is not found ? Care to create a quick stackblitz showing the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are importing from app.module or you main module, there is no need to re import in any other module.

app.module.ts

```
import {ModulesComponent} from './modules/modules.component';
import {SharedModule} from './shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({    
declarations: [
......
  ModulesComponent,
......
],
imports: [
......
  SharedModule,
......
],
exports: [
],
providers: [
],
bootstrap: []
});
```

modules.module.ts

```
import {ThirdPartyModulesModule} from '../third-party.module';
@NgModule({    
declarations: [],
imports: [
  ThirdPartyModulesModule
],
exports: [],
providers: [],
bootstrap: []
});
```

third-party.module.ts

```
import {NgbModule, NgbRatingModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {NgbTabsetModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  entryComponents: [],
  declarations: [ ],
  imports: [
    NgbModule,
    NgbRatingModule,
    NgbTabsetModule
  ],
  exports: [
    NgbModule,
    NgbRatingModule,
    NgbTabsetModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
})
```